# joomla function require fatal error

Tags: php, joomla, fatal-error

I have a problem which suddenly appeared on my site...
It seems like a problem with php version on my hosting but don't know how to fix it and could use any help...

My site runs on J 1.5.16 (I know it's not up to date...) and yesterday was running just fine.

the error is:

```
Warning: require(/templates/xxx/gk_suckerfish.php) [function.require]: failed to open  stream: No such file or directory
in /home/xxx/public_html/templates/my_template/index.php on line 22

Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/templates/my_template/gk_suckerfish.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')
in /home/xxx/public_html/templates/my_template/index.php on line 22
```

Thanks!

Comment: The referenced file is either missing or not readable by PHP. By the way, you should have quotes around the filepath value in the require.

Comment: lines 22 and 23 of the index.php file are: require($mosConfig_absolute_path."/templates/" . $mainframe->getTemplate() . "/gk_suckerfish.php");
require($mosConfig_absolute_path."/templates/" . $mainframe->getTemplate() . "/gk_setup.php");

Comment: the both files are there, believe me :) just dont work anymore haha

Comment: Might be a setting your host has changed on the server

Comment: But can you verify that `/templates/my_template/gk_suckerfish.php` exists?  I am doubting that is the case as most wouldn't have a `/templates` directory directly below root.  So it would seem that you are not getting a proper value for `$mosConfig_absolute_path`.

Comment: @Lodder I think you are right, but don't know what is changed and how to fix it.

Comment: @Mike Brant, what do you suggest? How can I try to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution!

It seems that somehow the legacy plugin was disabled, I have enabled the plugin system-legacy and the site works fine again!

Now I really have to work on upgrading the website to at least j 2.5

P.S. The real problem was with j 1.5.17. which has serious issues with auto disabling the system-legacy plugin. I have updated the site to 1.5.26. and do not have this problem anymore!

Thank you all,
Best regards!